# Why it has HASH JOIN in this execution plan (explain plan)?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm testing some Oracle statements and their execution plan and having struggle with this one (inner joining 2 table):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM WF_TRANSITION T, 
     WF_VERSION_REQUEST_TYPE VRT 
WHERE T.FK_VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID = VRT.VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID + 0
```

Here's its execution plan:

[image: Execution plan for above SQL statement]

My question is why we have step 6 HASH JOIN, meanwhile we do NESTED LOOP before. I think this NESTED LOOP joined 2 table `WF_TRANSITION` and `WF_VERSION_REQUEST_TYPE` and no need HASH JOIN.
Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an adaptive plan. The database will choose to do either a `hash join` OR `nested loop` based on the number of rows processed.

You can tell this by the `statistics collector` step. This is counting the rows flowing out of the scan on `wf_version_reqeuest_types_pk`.

If this number stays below a threshold, it'll use the `nested loop`. Above this it'll switch to a `hash join`.

To find out which it did, get the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) for the query. If you add the `+ADAPTIVE` option when using `DBMS_XPlan`, it'll show you which join was discarded with by prefixing these operations with `-`:

```
set serveroutput off

select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */*
from   hr.employees e
join   hr.departments d
on     e.department_id = d.department_id;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ROWSTATS LAST +ADAPTIVE'));

Plan hash value: 4179021502                                                                 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   Id  | Operation                     | Name              | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|     0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                   |      1 |        |    106 |    
|  *  1 |  HASH JOIN                    |                   |      1 |    106 |    106 |    
|-    2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                   |      1 |    106 |     27 |    
|-    3 |    NESTED LOOPS               |                   |      1 |        |     27 |    
|-    4 |     STATISTICS COLLECTOR      |                   |      1 |        |     27 |    
|     5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | DEPARTMENTS       |      1 |     27 |     27 |    
|- *  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |      0 |        |      0 |    
|-    7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEES         |      0 |      4 |      0 |    
|     8 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL           | EMPLOYEES         |      1 |    107 |    107 |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                         
---------------------------------------------------                                         

   1 - access("E"."DEPARTMENT_ID"="D"."DEPARTMENT_ID")                                      
   6 - access("E"."DEPARTMENT_ID"="D"."DEPARTMENT_ID")                                      

Note                                                                                        
-----                                                                                       
   - this is an adaptive plan (rows marked '-' are inactive)
```

Comment: You had a great answer. Thanks for your explain. Can I asked you one more little question? I used hint to force NESTED LOOP join: ```SELECT /*+ USE_NL(T VRT) */ COUNT(*) FROM WF_TRANSITION T, WF_VERSION_REQUEST_TYPE VRT WHERE T.FK_VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID = VRT.VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID + 0```. Why its execution plan use INDEX FULL SCAN on both table: [link](https://i.imgur.com/M1PKzAK.png) . I think it should use index on WF_TRANSITION on NESTED LOOP join. Additional info: WF_TRANSITION has 785 rows, non-unique, WF_VERSION_REQUEST_TYPE has 90 rows, unique primary key. Really a strange thing to me.

Comment: `VRT.VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID + 0` applies a function; this prevents `index range` scans. Remove `+ 0`

Comment: I intentionally add ```VRT.VS_REQUEST_TYPE_ID + 0``` to use ```VRT``` table (which has 90 rows) as driving table for ```NESTED LOOP``` and the optimizer must use ```index range scans``` on index of ```WF_TRANSITION T``` table (which has 785 rows). However, the optimizer uses ```fast full scan``` on ```T``` table. Can you explain this? It's really strange.

Comment: Trying to outsmart the optimizer like this is generally a bad idea. Provided its stats are accurate, it usually gets good plans. If removing `+ 0` doesn't give the "right" plan, submit a new question including the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) you get. Use `dbms_xplan` like I've done above to do this. Use `ALLSTATS LAST` for the format; ensure the plan includes the `A-rows`, `E-rows`, and `Buffers` columns. You can omit the adaptive options.